# Crystal Reports detail line section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have designed a report in Crystal Reports with multiple detail line sections, with values added from a data set. In both detail sections 'a' and 'b' there are 2 values.

When I view the report, value 1 is shown for both detail section 'a' and 'b', but only detail section 'a' shows value 2.

How can I view the entire detail section at once - and then only the next section - so that I can understand them separately? Please don't recommend sub reports.

Here's how it looks at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Hi Danish, welcome to SO. Your question is a little difficult to follow, so I've proposed an edit that hopefully clears it up a bit. I did have difficulty understanding what you were saying so if I have misrepresented the problem in my edits, please feel free to edit again.

Comment: my crystal report has two detail section (a,b). i have binded seperate fields in each the detail section , let say if the binding field has 2 values to be printed in details section so total elements in detail section will be 4, it now shows as section a's value 1 and then the section b's value 1 is shown i need keep detail section a and b seperate, now it shows mixed values both the detail section values are shown

Comment: thnks for looking into this matter tim

Comment: I see sub report is the only option though don't want to use it

Comment: in case when i use sub report only the total or one line can be viewed only,

Comment: i need a report inside another report

Comment: dear, as per yr screenshot, its not understand four variable value as you described in comment, could you circle it and paste again because your question is not clearly understand , how the data display in section?